# Create nested table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a complex table that has multiple nested rows.

My current understanding is that you can not have nested rows in an HTML table. For example,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>header one</td>
    <td>header two</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>
      <!-- nested row -->
      <tr>
        <td>nested one</td>
        <td>nested two</td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Would expect to create:

[image]

This is a very simple exaple. The table that I need to generate has several more nested rows.

I know that there is the table attribute `rowspan` to set rows. However, I'm wondering if there are any open-source JavaScript libraries or alternative methods for creating nested table rows, without having to use the `rowspan` attribute.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to wrap the nested `tr` in a new `table` element first. So it looks like:

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
td { border: 1px solid #000; }
td table { 
  margin: -2px;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>header one</td>
        <td>header two</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>
    
          <!-- nested row -->
          <table>
           <tr>
             <td>nested one</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>nested two</td>
           </tr>
          </table>
    
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

`tr` can only be a child of a `table`, `thead`, `tfoot`, etc.

`rowspan` is much easier to style, though:

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>header one</td>
        <td>header two</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">One</td>
        <td>nested one</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>nested two</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `<td rowspan="2">One</td>`

Comment: `rowspan` and `colspan`. thx.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to create a nested *table*:

```
<td>
  <!-- nested row -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>nested one</td>
      <td>nested two</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```