# I can't get value in Thymeleaf template th:each

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

- Java code

```java
int[] days = {Integer.valueOf(tokens[2])};

model.addAttribute("days", days);
```

- HTML code

```xml
<tr th:each="day : ${days}">
    <p th:text="${day}"></p>
    <p th:text="${dayStat.index}"></p>
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${day}"></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

- browser page source code

```
<tr>
    <p>28</p>
    <p>0</p>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

If I access through `th:each` in Thymeleaf, I can access right below.

However, if you go deeper into other tags, you cannot get the value.
I do not know why.

Can you tell me?

I expected:

- browser page source code

```
<tr>
    <p>28</p>
    <p>0</p>
    <tr>
        <td>28</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create nested table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118979/create-nested-table-rows)

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have a nested `<tr>` directly inside another `<tr>`. Instead, place the nested `<tr>` inside its own table. After you do that, Thymeleaf will render the inner `<td>`'s data correctly.